# is this some sort of haproxy bug?

Tags: haproxy

I go from http://sniffyourkid.com and then change the url to http://sniffyourkid.com/blog and it fails to go to apache and instead goes to my other webserver where sniffyourkid.com is. THIS IS INTERMITTENT and sometimes happens more often from www.sniffyourkid.com/ to www.sniffyourkid.com/blog.  If I refresh a few times it finally goes to apache.  It is soooo weird.  In wireshark, I see from the trace, it is incorrectly hitting the wrong webserver AND I see weird TCP out of order packets(not sure if it is important)

```
# this config needs haproxy-1.1.28 or haproxy-1.2.1

global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 4096
        #chroot /usr/share/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        #debug
        #quiet

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

frontend http_proxy
        bind 0.0.0.0:80
        acl is_blog path_beg /blog
        acl is_stats path_beg /haproxystats
        use_backend cluster2 if is_blog
        use_backend statistics if is_stats
        use_backend cluster1 if !is_blog !is_stats

backend statistics
        stats enable
        stats uri /haproxystats

backend cluster1
        option httpchk
        cookie  SERVERID rewrite
        server  server1 127.0.0.1:9080 cookie inst1cookie check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

backend cluster2
        option httpchk
        cookie  SERVERID rewrite
        server  server1 127.0.0.1:8080 cookie inst1cookie check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
```

I think this is the version, right....

```
root@Sniffy:/etc/haproxy# apt-show-versions haproxy
haproxy/precise uptodate 1.4.18-0ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your config is missing "option http-server-close" so it works in tunnel mode.